# find value in visual basic array given key value

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a page that displays 4 sponsors ads on each page load from 15 different sponsors.  The ads should be weighted in how often they appear based on the value of the sponsorship.  I've pulled off similar in php, but can't seem to get it in ASP

This is how I'm going about it:
1. create an array of sponsors, with one "column" representing the value of the sponsorship
2. sum the value of the sponsorships in the array
3. use the total to create a weight percentage for each sponsor in the array, and add this percentage as an additional "column" in the array
4. create a new array that duplicates sponsor values based on their weight

In ASP I ended up creating a 3 dimensional array that duplicates my initial Sponsors array of data based on its weight.  It appears to work- I can write the values of the array as I iterate through my 100 row newSponsors array.

newSponsors(n,x,i) = Sponsors(x,i)

Then I randomize 4 numbers out of 100 to create keys for my 3 dimensional array.  I'm stuck at how to compare them:

```
SponsorWeight = Sponsors(5,i)

Dim newSponsors(100,5,15)

for i = 0 to SponsorTotalCt
SponsorWeight = Sponsors(5,i)
for w = 1 to SponsorWeight
    for x = 0 to 5
        newSponsors(n,x,i) = Sponsors(x,i)
        value = Sponsors(x,i)
        response.write("Value = " & value & "<br>")
    next
    n = n + 1
next
x = 0
next
```

So say my Randomizer generates 4 random numbers out of 100:  17,9,88, and 27.  I need to create an if statement:

```
if newSponsors(17,2,i) = newSponsors(9,2,i)
  pass = false
```

but I don't know what the i value is going to be.  How do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it took a day and a half, but I finally came up with this working code- probably not the most effective method, but it does the job:

```
i = 0
For i = 0 to UBound(Sponsors, 2)
SponsorVal = Sponsors (2,i)
SponsorWeight = Round(SponsorVal/SponsorTotalAmt * 100,0)
Sponsors (5,i) = SponsorWeight

Next

'CREATE NEW ARRAY OF 100 TO RANDOMIZE AND WEIGHT
' n = key in 100 array
' x = key in Sponsors array
' i = row in Sponsors array
' w = weight in Sponsor array

Dim n
Dim x

n = 0
x = 0
i = 0
w = 1
SponsorWeight = Sponsors(5,i)

Dim newSponsors(100,15)

for i = 0 to SponsorTotalCt
SponsorWeight = Sponsors(5,i)
for w = 1 to SponsorWeight
    value = i
    newSponsors(n,0) = value
    response.write(value)
    n = n + 1
next
x = 0
next


' RANDOMIZE A VALUE FROM newSponsors

intHighNumber = n
intLowNumber = 1

pass = "false"

Dim spot(4)

For i = 1 to 4
    Randomize
    spot(i)= Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber)
Next

spot1 = spot(1)
spot2 = spot(2)
spot3 = spot(3)
spot4 = spot(4)

Sponsor1 = newSponsors(spot1,0)
Sponsor2 = newSponsors(spot2,0)
Sponsor3 = newSponsors(spot3,0)
Sponsor4 = newSponsors(spot4,0)

'MAKE SURE THAT THERE ARE NO DUPLICATE SPONSORS IN THE 4 RANDOMLY SELECTED

do
```

if newSponsors(spot1,0) <> newSponsors(spot2,0) AND newSponsors(spot1,0) <> newSponsors(spot3,0) AND newSponsors(spot1,0)<>newSponsors(spot4,0) AND newSponsors(spot2,0)<>newSponsors(spot3,0) AND newSponsors(spot2,0)<>newSponsors(spot4,0) AND newSponsors(spot3,0)<>newSponsors(spot4,0)then
        pass = "true"
    else
        pass = "false"
        For i = 1 to 4
            Randomize
            spot(i)= Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber)
            spot1 = spot(1)
            spot2 = spot(2)
            spot3 = spot(3)
            spot4 = spot(4)
            Sponsor1 = newSponsors(spot1,0)
            Sponsor2 = newSponsors(spot2,0)
            Sponsor3 = newSponsors(spot3,0)
            Sponsor4 = newSponsors(spot4,0)
        Next
    end if
    Loop Until pass = "true"

```
response.write("Pass: " & pass & "<br>")
Response.write(Sponsor1 & "<br>" & Sponsor2 & "<br>" & Sponsor3 & "<br>" & Sponsor4)

'CALL THE APPROPRIATE VALUE IN THE SPONSORS ARRAY BASED ON THE NEWSPONSORS ARRAY
Response.write("<br><br>" & Sponsors(Sponsor1,4))
```

Hope someone finds it helpful!